# Is better way to write this date range scope?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I have scope for selecting shifts:

```
scope :by_date, lambda { |date|
  where "end_date BETWEEN ? AND ? OR start_date BETWEEN ? AND ?", date.beginning_of_day, date.end_of_day, date.beginning_of_day, date.end_of_day
}
```

Is more cleaner way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scope :by_date, lambda { |date| 
  where("DATE(start_date) = :date OR DATE(end_date) = :date", date: date.to_date) 
}
```

Comment: You should change it to ``where(["DATE(start_date) = :date OR DATE(end_date) = :date", date: date.to_date]) }``

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
scope :by_date, lambda { |date|
  where("end_date BETWEEN :beginning AND :end OR start_date BETWEEN :beginning AND :end",
    beginning: date.beginning_of_day, end: date.end_of_day)
}
```